# CalDAV allprop not working as expected

Tags: curl, webdav, caldav

I am using CalDAV server.

When I send following request:

```
curl --request PROPFIND  --user admin:admin --header "depth:0" --header "Content-Type: text/xml"  --data "<D:propfind xmlns:D='DAV:'><D:prop><D:allprop/></D:prop></D:propfind>" http://example/calendars/users/admin/calendar/
```

I get response as follows:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multistatus xmlns='DAV:'>
  <response>
    <href>/calendars/users/admin/calendar/</href>
    <propstat>
      <prop>
        <allprop/>
      </prop>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>
    </propstat>
  </response>
```

If I understand correctly, CalDAV does support `allprop` as I looked at tutorials and examples.

If I change `allprop` to `displayname` or `acl`, it does work then.

Is `allprop` not supported or what is the new equivalent of `allprop`?

Or is my request bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your request is wrong.

The request, as you have it, is asking for a property `allprop`.

What you want to do is:

```xml
<D:propfind xmlns:D='DAV:'><D:allprop/></D:propfind>
```

Refer to the RFC 2518 section [8.1.2 Example - Using allprop to Retrieve All Properties](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2518#section-8.1.2)

Comment: It is even easier: A PROPFIND with an empty body is the same like an <allprop/> query. Content-Length:0 is sufficient. ("A client may choose not to submit a request body.  An empty PROPFIND request body MUST be treated as if it were an 'allprop' request.")